# webview and blocking xmlhttp request and fetch

Tags: cordova, webview, xmlhttprequest, fetch

As read on the google documentation, the latest released versions of the WebView API block calls to XMLHttpRequest and Fetch but does not explain how to get around this block.
Can anyone explain to me how to go about this problem?

Hello and thanks for the reply
I did this in the config.xml file:

```
<platform name="android">
        <preference name="scheme" value="https" />
        <preference name="hostname" value="radiomatese.it" />
        <icon src="res/android/icon.png" />
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
        <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
</platform>
```

And the script is this:

```
const url = "https://www.radiomatese.it/script/app/details.php";
        const response = await fetch(url);
        alert(response.status);
        if(response.ok) { return response.json(); } else { alert(response.error); }
```

But nothing, if I emulate with the browser everything works perfectly but if I emulate with an android device it does not run the fetch in fact it does not even give me alert(response.status)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your scheme and hostname to turn on CORS.

```
<preference name="scheme" value="https" />
<preference name="hostname" value="myapp" />
```

Comment: this where it has to be inserted and in the value I have to stay like this or insert something?

Comment: In your config.xml

Comment: I put this in the config.xml file but nothing doesn't work equally

Comment: Your back end needs to be CORS and accept origin https: // myapp

Comment: I have the .htaccess file in the back end like this: <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API
</IfModule>, I have the .htaccess file in the back end like this: